# Problem with husky_rviz, no tf data

Tags: gazebo, rviz, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with ubuntu 14.04 indigo. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/ros/Drive%20a%20Husky.html) and ran the `husky_gazebo` launch file first then the `husky_rviz` launch file. However, I cannot see the husky model shown in the tutorial in rviz. In the display panel, it shows me a `No tf data. Actual error: Fixed Frame [odom] does not exist`  in the global status. Also, the robotModel status is an error as well.

The only thing that I did differently then the tutorial is that I downloaded the all the gazebo models from this [link](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/downloads/), and moved all files to  `~/.gazebo/models/` folder. Also, instead of running `roscore`, I am running `sudo service husky-core start` on the actually Husky robot.

here is a screen shot of the gazebo view panel:
[image: image description]

rviz view panel:

[image: image description]

anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

tf tree:

[image: image description]

**update:**
When I first turn on the husky robot and starts the `husky-core`, then `roslaunch husky_viz view.robot.launch`, everything works fine in rviz. When I move the joystick controller, the actually husky moves and the simulated husky in rviz moves as well. Now, I am trying to use gazebo to simulate the husky by `roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_empty_world.launch`, then `roslaunch husky_viz view_robot.launch`, but the husky model does not show up in rviz.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295529/problem-with-husky_rviz,-no-tf-data/) by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2018-06-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-27**:
Can you post your tf tree?

**Comment by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on 2018-06-27**:
I added it, but it just shows no tf data received.

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-06-28**:
husky_gazebo , when you launch this , see to it that all the nodes are launched properly . Sometimes if dependencies are not installed , usually stuff like this happens .

**Comment by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on 2018-06-28**:
I checked with `rosdep check husky_gazebo` `rosdep check husky_viz` and it shows me that all the dependency are satisfied. Also, I downloaded those packets by `sudo apt-get install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out, I need to be using `roscore` instead of the actually `husky-core` inorder for the `husky_gazebo` and `husky_viz` to work. So, I followed this [link](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup#Single_machine_configuration) and configured my network, then everything works.

---

Originally posted by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) with karma: 62 on 2018-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0